# How do you work recursion out?

Tags: java, recursion

I have been given the following question:

Consider the following method. What should it return if `n == 3`?

```
public static String recEx(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
       return "";
    return recEx(n - 3) + n + recEx(n - 2) + n;
}
```

The answer is 3113. How and what do you do to achieve this answer?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746387/how-do-you-work-recursion-out) might help :P

Comment: for such small number of calls, use the pen and paper method, draw graph of method calls.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put a `System.out.println(n)` at the top of the method and you will see.

```
recEx(3) calls 
recEx(0)+3+recEx(1)+3
where recEx(1) is
""+1+""+1
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is using a pencil and a paper and start drawing things.

```
                 _recEx(3)_
                /          \
               /          recEx(1)
             recEx(0)     /       \
             /         recEx(-2)  recEx(-1)
            ""
```

When the value is `<= 0`, an empty String is returned, this value is pushed back to the caller... and that's the recursion! It's good to begin with smaller example, say `n = 2`, or even `n = 1`, try to understand it and then apply it on bigger numbers.

A good practice is debugging your code and carefully following the debugger, step by step, see all the values and trying to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

```
recEx(3) = recEx(0) + 3 + recEx(1) + 3
recEx(0) = ""
recEx(1) = recEx(-2) + 1 + recEx(-1) + 1
recEx(-2) = ""
recEx(-1) = ""
```

So the answer is:

```
recEx(3) = recEx(0) + 3 + recEx(1) + 3
recEx(3) = "" + 3 + recEx(-2) + 1 + recEx(-1) + 1 + 3
recEx(3) = "" + 3 + "" + 1 + "" + 1 + 3
recEx(3) = "3113"
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with the base case: `n <= 0`

```java
recEx(0) ; ==> ""
```

When you look at the default case it will always reduce `n` on each recursion. Thus you should try `n == 1` and use the knowledge that when n <= 0 it can be replaced with "".

```java
recEx(1);                       ==> 
recEx(-2) + 1 + recEx(-1) + 1;  ==> 
"" + 1 + "" + 1;                ==>
"11"
```

Then you try `n == 2`

```java
recEx(2);                       ==> 
recEx(-1) + 2 + recEx(0) + 2;   ==>
"" + 2 + "" + 2;                ==>
"22"
```

Then you try `n == 3`. Here you use you prior knowledge of `recEc(1)`

```java
recEx(3);                       ==> 
recEx(0) + 3 + recEx(1) + 3;    ==>
"" + 3 + "11" + 3;              ==>
"3113"
```

There you go.. As you can see I go from the simplest and go backwards. I'm using substitution rules saying you can replace the result of a known result with a method call. As long as the method is functional (doesn't rely on enything else than arguments) you can do this.

For fun whats recEx(5) ? Well it must be like this:

```java
recEx(5);                       ==> 
recEx(2) + 5 + recEx(3) + 5;    ==>
"22" + 5 + "3113" + 5           ==>
"22531135"
```

It's quite simple when you already know the answers for `recEx(2)` and  `recEx(3)`.

Calculating `recEx(3)` starting with the default case works the same except you need to stop what you are doing at each level to calculate the result of the recursive call. Remember to keep track of which `n` you have calculated and it's result so you don't need to do same `n` several times like the computer actually does.

I find doing it the way I presented here much easier since you don't need to do several things in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to trace it:

when n=3
will call again for:

```
recEx(0) + 3 + recEc(1) + 3

recEx(0)  // will return empty string
```

and if you call for recEx(1) 
    recEx(-2)  + 1 + recEx(-1) + 1

```
recEx(-2)   // will return empty string
recEx(-1)   // will return empty string
```

so first will retun to calculate

```
 recEx(-2)  + 1 + recEx(-1) + 1 = "" + 1 + "" + 1  = "11"
```

and this result will back to the first caller

```
     recEx(0) + 3 + recEc(1) + 3 = "" + 3 + "11" + 3 = "3113"
```

and to print the result to console:

```
System.out.println(recEx(3));
```